# Extracting Email Domain from string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have string something like this

1. `'myname' <myname@mydomain.com>`

or like this

2. `myname@mydomain.com`

I want to extract domain from both kind of strings

For 2nd I can do somthing like this

```
select RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))
```

but same is not working for 1st string.

Also I do not know in which format email address will come

I am using Sql Server 2014.

Comment: If someone had a subdomain in their address what would you expect? For example `steve@sales.mybusiness.org.uk`

Comment: it should take  'sales.mybusiness.org.uk'

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stuff()` and `replace()`:

```
select replace(stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email), ''), '>', '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c00933a630e0cdb14e420365822d3057) is a db<>fiddle.